# Is there a way to use TensorFlow models in my website from JavaScript?

Tags: python, node.js, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I have a friend who uses Python and TensorFlow to build machine learning models. I want to use it in my website that has backend in nodejs.

Is there a way to incorporate a TensorFlow built and trained model into a JavaScript code so that I can provide machine learning based services on my website?

Comment: Why the many downvotes? This is a perfectly legitimate question, many people want to incorporate ML in everything, including their websites, and in fact, [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/) was invented for this exact purpose. Anyway, gave an answer. Consider switching your downvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at [TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/), which is specifically a browser-based JavaScript library for TensorFlow models.

More specifically, it is very likely that you can load your friend's model directly into your website with [`tf.loadModel()`](https://js.tensorflow.org/api/0.9.0/#loadModel) and then run it there.

There is a tutorial on [importing a Keras model into TensorFlow.js](https://js.tensorflow.org/tutorials/import-keras.html). Hopefully your friend will know what Keras is and how to produce his model in Keras.

If it's straight-up TensorFlow, then follow [this guide](https://github.com/tensorflow/tfjs-converter) how to convert his model to TensorFlow.js.

Comment: Thank you! I am curious what did people use before TensorFlow.js?

Comment: Well I did that myself back in the day... :) [TensorFlow serving](https://www.tensorflow.org/serving/) would run as a daemon, then you have some python server doing the feeding, and you connect to that from JavaScript. Kind of cumbersome.